# Integer Programming Constraint For NOR Gate

Tags: constraints, logical-operators, linear-programming, nor

For a set of binary variables *X = {x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ..., x<sub>n</sub>}* (n>=1). Lets define sum operation for simplicity: *sum(X) = x<sub>1</sub> + x<sub>2</sub> + ... + x<sub>n</sub>*

For another binary variable **y**, I want to write a constraint or more to represent this NOR behaviour:

- if sum(X) = 0 then y = 1
- if sum(X) > 0 then y = 0

I have achived this behaviour, but my solution needs an extra binary variable *z* that satisfies y + z = 1

By adding an extra variable I transformed my original requirement to OR gate.

- if sum(X) = 0 then z = 0
- if sum(X) > 0 then z = 1

My solution is:

0 <= n*z − sum(X) <= n−1

y + z = 1

I need another solution that does not require an extra variable.

Comment: This depends on a lot of things including your vector length and objective. There is not enough information to answer the question. Slow your code.

Comment: @Reinderien You are right I should have specified n>=1. Objective is irrelevant I think. All I needed is to exclude one of my constraints for the specific case. The specific case is "not selecting any variable from X" and for that case I needed a dummy variable for the constraint. I called that dummy variable "y". But NOR behaviour between set of X and y are not enough for me to feed Gurobi. Therefore I needed a linear programming constraint. Which I have managed to obtain in the answer

Comment: The objective determines whether the upper or lower constraints are needed at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Lower Bound for the constraint: 1
- Upper Bound for the constraint: n
- coefficient of variable y for the constraint: n
- coefficients for the variables x for the constraint: 1 for each

Mathematical representation of the constraint:  **1 <= ny + sum(X) <= n**

If any of the Xs are 1, then y has to be 0; if all of the Xs are 0, then y has to be 1.